# Slowly Changing Dimensions - exact SQL query implementation to retrieve correct data

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I'm a bit new to BI development/ data warehousing, but am facing the old Slowly Changing Dimensions dilemma. I've read a lot about the types and theory, but have found little in terms of, what I view, would be the most common SELECT queries against these implementations.

I'll keep my example simple. Say you have four sales reasons, East, West, North, and South. You have a group of salespeople that make daily sales and (maybe once a year) get reassigned a new region.

So you'll have raw data like the following:

```
name; sales; revenue; date
John Smith; 10; 5400; 2015-02-17
```

You have data like this every day.

You may also have a dimensional table like the following, initially:

```
name; region
John Smith; East
Nancy Ray; West
Claire Faust; North
```

So the sales director wants to know the monthly sales revenue for the East region for May 2015. You would execute a query:

```
SELECT region, month(date), sum(revenue)
from Fact_Table inner join Dim_Table on name = name
where region = East and date between ....
[group by region, month(date)]
```

You get the idea. Let's ignore that I'm using natural keys instead of surrogate integer keys; I'd clearly use surrogate keys.

Now, obviously, sales people may move regions mid year. Or mid month. So you have to create a SCD type in order to run this query. To me personally, Type 2 makes the most sense. So say you implement that. Say John Smith changed from East region to West region on May 15, 2015. You implement the following table:

```
name; region; start_date; end_date
John Smith; East; 2015-01-01; 2015-05-15
John Smith; West; 2015-5-15; 9999-12-31
```

Now the sales director asks the same question. What is the total sales revenue for the East for May 2015? Or moreover, show me the totals by region by month for the whole year. How would you structure the query?

```
SELECT region, month(date), sum(reveneue)
from Fact_Table inner join Dim_Table
on name = name
and date between start_date and end_date
group by region, month(date)
```

Would that give the correct results? I guess it might --- my question may be more along the lines of --- okay now assume you have 1 million records in the Fact table ... would this inner join be grossly inefficient, or is there a faster way to achieve this result?

Would it make more sense to write the SCD (like region) directly into a 'denormalized' Fact table --- and when the dimension changes, perhaps update a week or two's worth of Fact record' regions retroactively?

Comment: I don't think that your example is helping, as the region and sales person would clearly be different dimensions. The structure you outline makes it very difficult to efficiently structure the query for the basic question you want to ask, and that's an indication that the model is wrong. As soon as you need a complex query, you have to re-assess your dimensional structure.

Comment: It's a fairly common example in most SCD literature, actually. My 'real life' example is pretty much the same. A list of names belonging to various reigional offices (USA vs. Europe vs. Asia) ... some applications do not have a direct 'region' data point ... or even 'department' data point ... those are coded separately. ALL you have is the employee name from the application. The 'master reference' referring such employee back to a regional office, or a department (marketing vs. customer service) ... is TIME BASED. I don't understand how you are saying the data model is wrong.

Comment: In essence, the one link, in my example, from revenue to Region must ALWAYS go through employee first, as a circumstance of the data. It may help understanding if you replace 'Region' with 'department'.

Comment: The model is fine for an OLTP system, not for a dimensional one. When you add a fact to the table you already have the name, and you know which region they were attached to, so you add both as different keys. Clearly from the reporting point of view the important issues are the revenue by region, the revenue by name, and the revenue by both region and name. Your SCD structure makes the second of these rather tricky. Alternatively, if you have a synthetic key for the dimension then just create a new dim value for every valid combination of name and region.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to write the correct 'region' at the time the fact table is generated (because employee ID will be in the fact table) ... however ... I'm working from the assumption that retro-active corrections will be necessary. Aka someone will change regions and HR/ the tech team/ our process may not notice this for a week or two perhaps. I guess I can still attach a region ID to the fact table at the time of writing it, but in order to maintain data integrity and be able to make retroactive updates, I'd still need an 'effective date' table. Maybe just for corrections vs. steady joins

Answer (score 2):

Your concept is correct if your business requirement has a hierarchy of Region->Seller, as shown in your example.

The performance of your current query may be challenging, but it will be improved by the use of appropriate dimension keys and attributes.

Use a date dimension hierarchy that includes date->Month, and you'll be able to avoid the range query.

Use integer, surrogate, keys in both dimensions and your indexing performance will improve.

One million rows is tiny, you won't have performance problems on any competent DBMS :)

Comment: Yes that makes sense -- I'll keep those tips in mind. What do you mean by date dimension hierarchy? You mean in the dimension table with the 'effective' dates --- write the month in the table as well at the time of the insert/ table write?

Comment: For dates, you should have a dimension that is something like:

dim_date(id,date_business_key,day,month,year,day_of_week, month_name, etc)

Your fact table should only contain a foreign-key reference to the dim_date table.

To find the sales in a given month, query the join of your fact + dim_date, where the year and month are your required values.

Comment: That makes sense except that, if a salesman was only in the 'East' for half a month, from Jun 1st to Jun 15th .... then summing the 'total' for the East range still requires splitting data at the date granularity, not simply the month.

Comment: That's actually handled by the date dimension. I can't do formatting here, so I hope you can understand this query :) select seller,sum(sale_amount) from fact_sale inner join dim_date on dim_date.id = fact_sale.date_id inner join dim_seller on dim_seller.id = fact_sale.seller_id where dim_date.year = 2015 and dim_date.month = 6 and dim_seller.region = 'Northern'. This will give you the total sales made by each seller when they made sales in the Northern region in June 2015.