# Optimal query/join for joining scd-type-2 dimension with facts for reporting/aggregation

Tags: sql, apache-spark, query-optimization, data-warehouse, scd

I have a fact table and an scd-type-2 dimension table. I want to produce sales report by region and year.

I have working solution with a query that joins them for reporting purposes. When I run the query in spark/databricks, it gives me a little warning at the bottom: `Use range join optimization: This query has a join condition that can benefit from range join optimization. To improve performance, consider adding a range join hint.` and points to [this link](https://docs.databricks.com/optimizations/range-join.html).

**Question:** Is there a more optimal way to query when I'm joining using a `between` condition (instead of `=` condition)?

`fact table:`

```sql
create table sales
(name             string
,sale_date        date
,sold_amt         long);

insert into sales values
('John','2022-02-02',100),
('John','2022-03-03',100),
('John','2023-02-02',200),
('John','2023-03-03',200),
('Rick','2022-02-02',300),
('Rick','2023-02-02',400);
```

`dimension table (scd-type-2)`

```sql
create table employee_scd2
(name        string
,region      string
,start_date  date,
,end_date    date,
,is_current  boolean); -- unused, kept for completeness

insert into employee_scd2 values
('John','NAM',  '2010-01-01', '2022-12-31', false),
-- John transferred from NAM to APAC starting 2023
('John','APAC', '2023-01-01', '9999-01-01', true),
('Rick','NAM',  '2020-01-01', '9999-12-31', true);
```

`sales report by region and year`

```sql
select e.region,
       year(s.sale_date) as sale_year,
       SUM(s.sold_amt)   as sale_amt
from       sales s
left join  employee_scd2 e
  on     e.name       = s.name
  and    s.sale_date between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by e.region, year(s.sale_date);
```

---

I've read following and some more:

- [Slowly Changing Dimensions - exact SQL query implementation to retrieve correct data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149779/slowly-changing-dimensions-exact-sql-query-implementation-to-retrieve-correct)
- [Join Fact table to SCD Type 2 ... how to write query? (SQL Server)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184639/join-fact-table-to-scd-type-2-how-to-write-query-sql-server)
- https://www.startdataengineering.com/post/how-to-join-fact-scd2-tables/
- [How to implement Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD2) Type 2 in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058951/how-to-implement-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd2-type-2-in-spark)

Comment: Maybe fire your data modeler?  Take a look at Kimball-methodology star schemas.  The join you have defined is far more complicated than what should never be required for a simple question from a well-designed data mart.

Comment: I’d start by reading about surrogate keys

Comment: @NickW, I suspect surrogate keys would require that the dimension table always receives the changes BEFORE the fact, right? Or is there some technique that would allow me to use surrogate key in the join, even if the facts came today and the "corresponding" dimension updates came tomorrow. Of course I would expect my queries to return correct results only after tomorrow.

Comment: It is unusual, but not unheard of, for fact and dimension data to arrive at different times. However, the Kimball methodology covers this if you search within it for “late arriving dimensions”